# Получение имени массива из тега <select>

Tags: javascript, html

Есть раскрывающийся список:

```
<select id='dropDown' onchange='somethingDoer(this);'>
    <option value='0' arrayType='companies'>ООО "Рога и Копыта"</option>
    <option value='1' arrayType='companies'>ООО "Ромашка"</option>
    <option value='2' arrayType='companies'>ЗАО "Вектор"</option>
    <option value='0' arrayType='personas'>Иванов И.И.</option>
    <option value='1' arrayType='personas'>Петров П.П.</option>
    <option value='2' arrayType='personas'>Сидоров С.С.</option>
</select>
```

Список составлен из двух массивов данных "companies" и "personas". Мне хотелось бы, чтобы при выборе опции из выпадающего списка в функцию somethingDoer(this); передавалось не только значение value 0-2, т.е. порядковый номер записи внутри массива, но и название самого массива, чтобы функция смогла обратиться к нему напрямую. Как это реализовать, либо если конструкция некорректная, как нужно ее переписать, чтобы получить желаемый результат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы наверно хотите что-то подобное:

```js
function somethingDoer(dropDown) {
    var option = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex];
    console.log(option.value, option.getAttribute('arrayType'));
}
```

```html
<select id='dropDown' onchange="somethingDoer(this)">
    <option value='0' arrayType='companies'>ООО "Рога и Копыта"</option>
    <option value='1' arrayType='companies'>ООО "Ромашка"</option>
    <option value='2' arrayType='companies'>ЗАО "Вектор"</option>
    <option value='0' arrayType='personas'>Иванов И.И.</option>
    <option value='1' arrayType='personas'>Петров П.П.</option>
    <option value='2' arrayType='personas'>Сидоров С.С.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: не надо ничего искать: `var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];`

Comment: @Nikita A. Slutsky selectedIndex это как раз то, что мне было нужно, спасибо.

Comment: @Igor, действительно. Благодарю за комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function somethingDoer(e){
  console.log(e.value +':'+ e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute("arrayType"));
}
```

```html
<select id='dropDown' onchange='somethingDoer(this);'>
    <option value='0' arrayType='companies'>ООО "Рога и Копыта"</option>
    <option value='1' arrayType='companies'>ООО "Ромашка"</option>
    <option value='2' arrayType='companies'>ЗАО "Вектор"</option>
    <option value='0' arrayType='personas'>Иванов И.И.</option>
    <option value='1' arrayType='personas'>Петров П.П.</option>
    <option value='2' arrayType='personas'>Сидоров С.С.</option>
</select>
```